# How could Doraemon make money?

Tags: doraemon

In many episode of doraemon (oldest and newest) or even the movie, he always buy so many tools from department store, mostly his "magical"/future gadget that will be used by Nobita. Where did he got all of the money ?

I never seen him working since his duty and goal was to make Nobita have a happy future.

Comment: maybe the one that Doraemon used are actually cheap? Sewashi must have provided him some of the gadget beofer giving Doraemon to Nobita. Sometimes Nobita used some of them without Doraemon knowing and they ended up can't afford it

Comment: Maybe, Dora used time machine to go to the future and see which lottery number wins, then returned to the present and buy that lottery ticket. Maybe.

Comment: It's assumed that maybe he invests/exchanges the Showa era money he gets from running errands from doing household errands somewhereInterests and stuff build up in time... old money might be worth more in the future.

Comment: Probably Nobita Mom give Doraemon the pocket money and maybe he save it and then he can buy it if the amount is affordable.

Comment: The creator didn't specify this part, so I would say the source is incompletely... you can assume that maybe Sewashi gave him the money before doraemon come to find Nobita.

Answer (score 3):

It not clearly mentioned anywhere that how Doraemon earns money. But by watching Episodes of Doraemon we can come to conclusions of earning resources.

**1. Owner of Doraemon (Nobita's great-great-grandson - Sewashi) is funding Doraemon.**

The reason for which Doraemon came from future is that to improve the academic performance of Nobita. Because of this reason Nobita's great-great-grandson was getting very less pocket money. If Nobita's great-great-grandson was rich then he did not required to have send Doraemon back into the past to Nobita. That means Nobita's great-great-grandson would have not been funding much to 
   Doraemon. That cut out this funding possibility.

**2. Through money making gadgets.**

Doraemon possesses quite a few money making gadgets like rice cake maker, time cloth, multiplying bank and so on. Since he is from the future, he knows how to use these gadgets to support himself. Also, he has the ‘Devil’s Passport’ which is the ‘Ultimate Credit Card’ as you can use it to get anything for free, absolutely.
But sometimes Doraemon also runs out of money as these gadgets does not provide a lot of money, as if they did **Sewashi (Nobita's great-great-grandson)** would have not send Doraemon on the first place.

So, I think point number 2 is the answer to your question.

**Note :** Name of characters has been referred from this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doraemon_characters